# Resampling probability

Tags: probability, resampling

I have a population of *n* unique items and am taking a sample of *r*. I am sampling with replacement. I would like to calculate the probability of sampling any specific item *x* times give the sample size and population.

Answer (score 2):

Let 'S' be an event of occurring that specific item, $P(S)=\frac{1}{n}$

Now, from $r$ samples occurrence of $S$ for $x$ times follow binomial distribution.

Hence,$$P(S=x)=\binom{r}{x}\times \Big(\frac{1}{n}\Big)^x\times\Big(\frac{n-1}{n}\Big)^{r-x}$$

Comment: This of course assumes that each item has an equal probability of selection.

Comment: @StatsStudent Yes!